# Unix networking in C++ doesn't wait for a connection

Tags: c++, networking, unix-socket

I have recently been learning about networking in Unix, and have written these 2 simple programs that waits for a connection, receives a message, then sends the same message back to the sender:

Send.cpp

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    getaddrinfo(NULL,  "2000", &hints, &res);

    int sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (auto error = connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0){
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }

    char msg[] = "Hello, World";
    send(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    char input[sizeof(msg)];
    recv(sockfd, &input, sizeof(input), 0);
    std::cout << input << '\n';
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

receive.cpp

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd, new_fd;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, "2000", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    listen(sockfd, 5);

    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr1;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    addr_size = sizeof(their_addr1);
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr1, &addr_size);
    if (new_fd < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << '\n';
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Accepted" << '\n';

    char msg[255];
    auto n = recv(new_fd, &msg, 255, 0);
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
    send(new_fd, &msg, n, 0);

    close(sockfd);
    close(new_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

If I run `receive.cpp`, then quickly (within about 5 or so seconds) run `send.cpp`, (running both from the command line) the programs work perfectly, but if I take any longer than that, then the send program just always gets a Connection Refused error and the receive program never terminates. It was my understanding that the `accept()` call would block the rest of the application and continue listening until a valid connection appears. Is this not how it works? Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: You should not be specifying `AI_PASSIVE` in `send.cpp`, see: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html.  Maybe it's that.

Comment: Even when I replaced that with the machines local IP address that same behaviour occurs, I used AI_PASSIVE just so it would work on both of my machines without having to modify the code

Comment: The problem is not what you think it is. First, **check the return value of `bind`** (as of every other function). Second, look up `SO_REUSEADDR` and `TIME_WAIT`

Comment: `if (auto error = connect(...) < 0)` doesn't set `error` to what you think, since `<` has a higher precedence than `=`. Use `int error; if ((error = connect(...)) < 0)` instead. Also, you are not checking the return value of `getaddrinfo()` or `bind()` or `listen()`. The parameters being used by `send.cpp` for `getaddrinfo()` are wrong for `connect()`.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.

The problem is that the binding was failing due to a "Address already in use" that was being caused because the TCP/IP protocol waits for a specific time to make sure all packets have arrived before allowing the same IP and Port combo to be used again.

Fix:

1. Wait for the kernel to give up the port.
2. Set the the socket options to allow for reuse of the same port using the
   setsockopt()

   int yes=1;
   if (setsockopt(listener,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof yes) == -1) {
   perror("setsockopt");
   exit(1);
   }